# Display &#8211 text with Smileys in windows phone 8.1 C# (smileys are look like &#8211.)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-phone-8.1, textblock

I have a string from server that contains content string with html tags and smileys are there.

I'm able to get rid of HTML tags with this,

string get_title_with_noHTML = Regex.Replace(get_title, @"<[^>]+>| ", "").Trim();

But the smileys are as it is. Not able to get solution for smileys while surfing much.

Here is the windows phone screen Shot:
[image]

The smileys look like the red square area.
I have tried this with RichTextblock but richtextblock hasn't the text property.

I tried with this RichTextBlock [Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/586214/Text-Binding-to-WinRT-RichTextBlock).

```
       var control = sender as RichTextBlock;
      if (control != null)
      {
      control.Blocks.Clear();
      string value = e.NewValue.ToString();

      var paragraph = new Paragraph();
      paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run {Text = value});
      control.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
 }
```

but the result isn't the exact.

How can I get the exact smileys? what would be the possible solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any one here stack overflow doesn't allow to reply on this question

Comment: Any help with this. I am facing the same problem

Comment: I got a solution with this... check answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution for this.

```
 string header_dashboard = Windows.Data.Html.HtmlUtilities.ConvertToText(YouStringswith_&#8221);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am trying it on WP8.0 solved the problem with System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(value);